# taking FFT from DCT

Tags: signal-processing, speech

I have a problem in the following case:

There is a speech signal in time domain(`y[n]`).

For taking it into frequency domain, DCT has been get from `y[n]`(`w=dct(y)` in Matlab Sotware).

After it, for applying LPC on this signal(`w[k]`) in frequency domain for finding coefficients, the following process has been used:

```
{
  yfft=fft(w);
  yidft=ifft(yfft.*conj(yfft));
  a=levinson(yidft,p);
}
```

My question in here, is that, taking fft from dct signal(i.e. w), which domain do give us? (while, taking fft from a signal give frequency domain, am I right?)

Comment: This question better asked on http://dsp.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about [FDLP](https://github.com/iiscleap/FeatureExtractionUsingFDLP/blob/master/fdlpar.m) and corresponding paper [Speech Coding Based On Spectral Dynamics](https://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/146183/files/motlicek-tsd-2006.pdf) then "domain" does not take much sense actually. You have just some numbers calculated with the algorithm which are not really represented by any "domain". The numbers have some meaning but not really straightforward physical meaning which you can call "time domain".

In the algorithm you forgot that subband filter is applied on DCT, so it is not the whole signal anymore but just a filtered signal.

Same in cepstrum, for example. You have time domain, then frequency domain, then you take a logarithm and inverse Fourier transform but result is not time or frequency anymore, it has special name "quefrency" but you can also treat them as just numbers.

I would simply treat them as numbers.

Comment: No, I'm talking about this code: https://github.com/iiscleap/FeatureExtractionUsingFDLP/blob/master/fdlpar.m

Comment: about "do_lpc" function in this code that gives dct transformed signal.

Comment: Ok, you should have included it in the question.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response.